# Thymeleaf nested object form binding not generating good input name

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a following object structure:

```
public class A{

    private int id;
    private B objB;

    public A(){}

    --- setters & getters ---
}
```

This is my class B:

```
public class B{

    private int id;
    private int test;

    public B(){}

    --- setters & getters ---
}
```

Im passing an A object to my view and i want to create a form to my B object:

```
<form id="bForm" th:object=${A.objB} th:action="@{/save}">
    <input th:field=*{test} type="text"/>
</form>
```

However the above code will work it will generate the input name like this: `objB.test` and for this my controller cannot bind it to a B object.

This is the receiving method in my controller:

```
    @RequestMapping("/save")
    @ResponseBody
    public String setB(@ModelAttribute("bForm") B b, BindingResult result) {
        aService.setB(b);
        return "...";
    }
```

How can i set Thymeleaf to name my fields without the prefix so instead of: `objB.test` just `test`?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [thymeleaf-spring docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#handling-the-command-object):

> Values for `th:object` attributes in form tags must be variable expressions (`${...}`) specifying only the name of a model attribute, without property navigation. This means that an expression like `${seedStarter}` is valid, but `${seedStarter.data}` would not be.

<s>Try using a `th:with` attribute before your form to assign your `A.objB` variable and, therefore, avoid using property navigation in the `th:object` attribute.</s>

It seems that to adhere to this requirement you have to set an additional model attribute in your Spring controller's handler method that is handling the initial form rendering. So given that you already have something like this in some part of your code:

```
model.addAttribute("A", new A());
```

add another line:

```
model.addAttribute("bForm", new B());
```

Keep in mind to keep the model attribute name consistent with the one you had set  in `@ModelAttribute` annotation in your submission request handler you've posted in your question.

Comment: Thank you for your help. But i think i'm not referring to a property in this case. I'm referring to a concrete model and that model is the B class. Unfortunately <c:set> is a jsp tag so i cannot use it in a html file. What i did try though is to create local variable with th:with but that doesn't solve it as well.

Comment: Of course you are right, I meant the `th:with` attribute, but got them somehow mixed up, lol (I edited the answer now). But since you already tried that, was the result the same as without using `th:with`?

Comment: here is my sample:
 `<div th:with="objB = ${A.objB}">
    <form method="post" th:object="${objB}">`

This will throw me an error: 
`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'objB' available as request attribute`

Comment: Interesting... Please see my updated answer (sorry for misleading you initially).

Comment: so basically it is not possible to solve how i would wanted to do. That's sad but thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a late answer, but if objectB is inner object of A, then you can bind fields to B as inner object of A and process objectA in your controller.

It would look something like this, but in my case prompt is Arraylist of contained objects here:

```
    <th:block th:each="pr, stat : ${taskExecution.prompt}">
      <input type="hidden" id="hiddenName" th:field="*{prompt[__${stat.index}__].name}" th:value="${pr.name}">
      <input type="hidden" id="hiddenValue" th:field="*{prompt[__${stat.index}__].value}" th:value="${pr.value}">
    </th:block>
```